# Validating form with N number of same attributes

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I am trying to validate form with multiple number of fields with same 'name' attribute.

Form for First user:

```
class BuyTicketFormEmail(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name_customer = forms.CharField(max_length=191)
    last_name_customer = forms.CharField(max_length=191)
```

Form for additional Users

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    first_name_user = forms.CharField(max_length=191)
    last_name_user = forms.CharField(max_length=191)
```

form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF13g.jpg
Customer can add multiple additional users, I don't know exact number, all have same name.

In HTML I am displaying one form only, How can I validate this?

Comment: take a look at django formsets : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets.  This is a tutorial I like: https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d

Comment: @HenryM I don't want to save data, just want to validate it, Plus model has more fields, I am generating hash and etc. for each additional user

Comment: But the principles are all there, just don't do the save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exact length (N), but your answer helped my to find solutiuon, Thanks

```
names = request.POST.getlist('first_name')
surnames = request.POST.getlist('last_name')
id = 0
for name in names:
    data = {
        'first_name': name,
        'last_name': surnames[id]
    }
    users_form = self.users_form_class(data)
    id += 1
    if users_form.is_valid():
        f_name = users_form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        l_name = users_form.cleaned_data['last_name']
    else:
        return HttpResponse('String is too long, or containts incorrect characters')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not home, i wrote it using my smartphone, sorry if the code is not 100% correct. But you will get the big lines.

For the view :

```
def add_user(request):
    i = 1
    n = 5 #change it to the number of users you want
    all_users_forms = []
    while i < n+1 :
        one_user_form = UserForm()
        all_users_forms += one_user_form
        i += 1
    context = {'all_users_forms':all_users_forms}   
    template = 'form.html' #change it to your template name
    return render(request, template, context)
```

In template to render yours forms

```
{% for form in all_users_forms %}
{{ form }}
```